# La clase Scanner con nextLine() se salta una linea de mi codigo

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Con el siguiente código, en el case 2 del switch, el metodo nextLine() no funciona correctamente. Cuando sale por consola para introducir nombre y telefono, se juntan los dos textos de "introduce nombre" e "introduce telefono" y coge solo el valor de uno de los métodos asignándoselo a telefono. Es decir, omite uno de los metodos nextLine(), en concreto, el que corresponde a la variable nombre. Creo haberlo usado así en varios ejercicios y nunca me había pasado esto. Utilizo Eclipse IDE, que no se si tendrá que ver.

opcion = scanner.nextInt();

```
        switch (opcion) {
        
        case 1:
            agenda.iniciarAgenda();
            break;
        case 2:
            
            System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
            nombre=scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Introduce telefono");
            telefono=scanner.nextLine();
            
            agenda.agregarContacto(nombre, telefono);
            
            break;
```

La salida por consola es la siguiente:

Introduce nombre

Introduce telefono

Carlos

Comment: Es el típico problema del método `nextInt` que no consume el salto de línea.  Cambia `opcion = scanner.nextInt();` por `opcion =Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());` y debería funcionarte bien. Otra solución es mantener tu código tal y como está pero agregar un `scanner.nextLine();` justo debajo de `opcion = scanner.nextInt();`.

Comment: Correcto, al modificarlo como dices los nextLine() funcionan correctamente. Gracias!